# Mass renormalization of the Schwinger model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, renormalization, self-energy

If there are no divergent diagrams in the self-energy, is the bare mass equal to the renormalized mass in the continuum limit Schwinger model with 1 flavour in 1+1 dimensions?

Let $m_r$ = renormalized mass, $Z =$ renormalizing factor for the fermion field (ie $\psi_0 = \sqrt{Z}\psi)$, $m_b$ = bare mass. Then following (24.7) in [http://fma.if.usp.br/~burdman/QFT1/lecture_24.pdf](http://fma.if.usp.br/%7Eburdman/QFT1/lecture_24.pdf) we have:

$$m_r + dm = Zm_b.$$

So essentially what I am asking is whether $Z = 1$ and $dm = 0$ in the Schwinger model where I believe the self-energy has no divergent diagrams.

The only divergent diagram in the theory is in the vacuum polarization with 2 fermions forming 1 loop as mentioned below (68) in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9704064.

Comment: No divergences would mean there exists a scheme where they are equal.

Comment: @ConnorBehan If I understand correctly, this scheme that you are referring to will need to enforce $Zm_b-dm$ != $m_b$, such that we end up with $m_r = m_b$ from the definition above. Something that can be done since there are no independent infinities for the $Z$ and $dm$ to cancel and given their arbitrariness, we can choose them to satisfy the above enforcing condition. Is this correct?